# How to add headers,checkboxes and submit/cancel button to form table php?

Tags: php, html, forms

I need to create a form with extracts data from a csv file, amongst other types of data I have on my code.

```
<html>
<body>
<table border=1px solid black>
<?php
$fp=fopen('sample.csv','r');
while(($data=fgetcsv($fp,1000,";"))!==FALSE){
    $user=$DB->get_record('user',array('username'=>trim($data[0])));
    echo '<tr><td>' . $data[0] . '</td><td>' . $user->firstname . '</td><td>' . $user->lastname . '</td><td>' . array_shift($dataClipNumber) . '</td><td>' . $data[1] .'</td><td>'.whatCourse(array_shift($dataClipCourse)).  '</td></tr>';
}
fclose($fp);

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the output so far:
[image: form2]

I would like to add headings to each column. I tried to put the th tags between tr and td, but it showed as another column instead. Other than that, I would like to add checkboxes next to all usernames( firstcolumn) And can they come checked by default?
Lastly, put a submit button which saves the usernames who are checkedmarked and calls my enrollment code (doing a moodle plugin of enrollment).

Thank you.

EDIT: It worked :) Although the button still missing. About words with ',~ on them. Like the one in the picture Número. Any way to solve that in headings?

EDIT 2: Since i'm doing this on Moodle, i removed a variable which gave that greyish look to it, since that could be interfering with buttons. But no. Using a smaller example:

[image: Smaller table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add header outside of iteration;

```
<form id="form">
    <table border=1px solid black>
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Column-1</td>
            <td>Column-2</td>
            <td>Column-3</td>
            <td>Column-4</td>
            <td>Column-5</td>
            <td>Column-6</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $fp=fopen('sample.csv','r');
        while(($data=fgetcsv($fp,1000,";"))!==FALSE){
            $user=$DB->get_record('user',array('username'=>trim($data[0])));
            echo '<tr>' .
                '<td><input type="checkbox" name="username[]" value="' . $data[0] . '" checked="checked"/></td>' .
                '<td>' . $data[0] . '</td><td>' . $user->firstname . '</td>' .
                '<td>' . $user->lastname . '</td>' .
                '<td>' . array_shift($dataClipNumber) . '</td>' .
                '<td>' . $data[1] .'</td>' .
                '<td>' . whatCourse(array_shift($dataClipCourse)).  '</td>' .
            '</tr>';
        }
        fclose($fp);

        ?>
    </table>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();">Save</a>
</form>
```

**Edit:** You need to put ;

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

in to your html headers section to fix special character view on your page

Comment: Thank you for your help, however the checkboxes stay on top of the first column, so no usernames can't be seen. Sry if my explanation was ambiguous. Checkboxes next to their usernames. I tried to give checkboxes a column of their own, still no luck so far. And the button isn't seen.

Comment: Did you used my updated answer? Also can you share screen capture for your case?

Comment: @user3178356 see my updated answer. And button cannot be missing. How cannot see it?

Comment: @user3178356 see my updated answer. I have moved button out of table

Comment: No changes, still the same visual.

Comment: Strange, I have updated button with link with js function. See my updated answer. Could you please try that with updated code?

Comment: Im afraid the result is the same. :S

Comment: Ok there is different problem then. Pleas describe problem more detail

Comment: Ty, I see the button now. I commented all my code below the closing of the file, which is the process of enrollment amongst other things. <input type="submit" id="submitDetails" class="submitDetails" name="submitDetails" value="Submit Your Details"/>   The value can be an URL?

Comment: What was the problem? button value cannot be url

Comment: My html is true, but there is someething wrong with your extra php codes. It wiill be better checking php logs for any error, or warning

Comment: Thx, will do. One last thing that popped my mind. Is it possible to sort information of the last column? Or it is only possible only tables? The examples I find on the web talk about jquery and plugin installation and i'm not really confortable with that.

Comment: You can use this plugin https://datatables.net/ . You can sort any column you want

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to also set it to display a message if the file cannot be read or if the file is empty so that it doesn't look like it's just not executing if either event is true.

```
<!-- set action to processor URL -->
<form action="process" method="post">
    <table>
        <caption>Table Caption</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Column 4</th>
                <th>Column 5</th>
                <th>Course</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php   $fp=fopen('sample.csv','r');
        while(($data=fgetcsv($fp,1000,";"))!==FALSE){
            $user=$DB->get_record('user',array('username'=>trim($data[0]))); ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data[0]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user->firstname; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user->lastname; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo array_shift($dataClipNumber); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data[1]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo whatCourse(array_shift($dataClipCourse)); ?>
            </tr>
<?php   }
        fclose($fp);
?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6">
                    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</form>
```